# Return a value from void method

Tags: c#, powerpoint

Is there any way to somehow store a value from a `void` method? In particular, I am trying to get the animation effect data for a particular shape in a PowerPoint presentation and use it later:

```
object r = presentation.Slides[2].Shapes[3].PickupAnimation();
```

but the compiler says

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'void'

Of course, I can not edit this method and change it to return a value.

Comment: Could you change the signature and add an out parameter?

Comment: @SébastienSevrin nice try,but OP say can't change the signature

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. There is absolutely nothing I can do to PickupAnimation() except to call it.

Comment: Ok, so you can't achieve your task

Comment: @user1394252 - Nevermind, I thought it was your own method and you wanted it to stay void while returning a value. What you ask is fortunately not possible, because if it was, you could create a real mess

Answer (score 2):

If a method does not return a value or have a `ref/out` parameter, there's no way to store a "result", as there *is* no result.

You should check whether there is a method or property that returns the value you need, as the task you're asking for can not be achieved without modifying the method itself.

I'm not a VSTO expert, but I'm pretty sure there are properties or other methods apart from `PickupAnimation` that return to you the animation effect parameters.

---

To just copy the same animation parameters to another `Shape`, use the `ApplyAnimation` method, as in:

```
presentation.Slides[2].Shapes[3].PickupAnimation();
presentation.Slides[2].Shapes[4].ApplyAnimation();
```

It's like a clipboard for animation parameters. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.shape.applyanimation(v=office.14).aspx):

> Applies the last picked up animation to the Shape object.

Answer (score 0):

*If* there is a suitable function or property etc you can call to get a result after calling a `void` method you could wrap the logic up into an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx). This might be especially useful when you wish to use fluent syntax.

MSDN:

> Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types
>   without creating a new derived type, recompiling, or otherwise
>   modifying the original type. Extension methods are a special kind of
>   static method, but they are called as if they were instance methods on
>   the extended type. For client code written in C# and Visual Basic,
>   there is no apparent difference between calling an extension method
>   and the methods that are actually defined in a type.

For example, if you want to pick up the animation and return an `AnimationSettings` in a single operation you could write this extension method in a static class:

```
public static AnimationSettings PickupAnimationAndReturnSettings(this Shape shape)
{
    shape.PickupAnimation();
    return shape.AnimationSettings;
}
```

Note this is just an example to demonstrate the technique - I don't have any particular knowledge about the API in question.